# Capitalization of "Von diesen/jenen..."

Tags: vocabulary, capitalization, pronoun

I was wondering which is correct:

> Von diesen/jenen sind drei lustig.

or

> Von Diesen/Jenen sind drei lustig.

My intuition tells me that the second one is correct because *diesen* is the only subject.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`diesen` und `jenen` are *Demonstrativpronomen*, and as such they are not capitalized. It does not matter whether they are the subject of your sentence.

Your intuition seems to confuse the subject (*Subjekt*) with a noun (*Substantiv*) when it comes to capitalization.

Comment: So wie man `Auch er ist lustig` schreibt. Auch `er` ist kein Substantiv das man im Wörterbuch findet. Hier [ein Videotutorial](http://www.belleslettres.eu/artikel/indefinitpronomen-grossschreibung.php) zur Frage.